# Using the same X-Ray Tracing-ID for multiple lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

The Scenario is the following:

[image: Request Workflow]

I have a lambda function that is listening to APIGateway and send the incoming request to two RabbitMQ queues.
For each RabbitMQ queue, there is lambda listening and doing some work.
So I have now 3 lambda functions.

For start I can get the tracing-id from the first lambda and send it with message header to RabbitMQ but for the other lambda functions that are listening to RabbitMQ how can I configure them to use the same tracing-id?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon MQ is not integrated with X-Ray, so it will not relay on any tracing headers automatically.

To trace requests that don't have a tracing header, you have to enable active tracing in the function configuration. This will set an immutable trace ID automatically for you.

You cannot overwrite *this* trace ID from within the Lambda function.

Unfortunately, there is no solution to this unless you specify your own segment using the X-Ray API or SDK with the trace ID manually set.